# Jenkins build with ant does not produce a apk file

Tags: android, ant, jenkins

New to jenkins and trying to set up a build using ant

I have the following project structure.

```
-workspace 
 -- project-A
 -- project-B (Lib project used by project-A)
```

I ran the following command that I have found on jenkins website
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project

```
android update project -p project-A

android update lib-project --target "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18" --path project-B
```

It creates the build.xml file and the properties files.

I am using git. So have made sure everything is checked in.

When I try to build the project I get a success result back but there is no APK file outputted.   I have checked that I have the 'Post-build action' of 'Archive the artifacts'.

Here is my output from jenkins for the build

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Test.Android/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@git.kiwadigital.com/************* # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://git@git.kiwadigital.com/*************
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@git.************/************* +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision a5bcdc51c07300aa18244049bcf80b1282ff55d6 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f a5bcdc51c07300aa18244049bcf80b1282ff55d6
 > git rev-list a5bcdc51c07300aa18244049bcf80b1282ff55d6 # timeout=10
[workspace] $ /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/tools/hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation/Apache_Ant/bin/ant -file Project-A
Buildfile: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Test.Android/workspace/Project-A/build.xml

help:
     [echo] Android Ant Build. Available targets:
     [echo]    help:      Displays this help.
     [echo]    clean:     Removes output files created by other targets.
     [echo]               This calls the same target on all dependent projects.
     [echo]               Use 'ant nodeps clean' to only clean the local project
     [echo]    debug:     Builds the application and signs it with a debug key.
     [echo]               The 'nodeps' target can be used to only build the
     [echo]               current project and ignore the libraries using:
     [echo]               'ant nodeps debug'
     [echo]    release:   Builds the application. The generated apk file must be
     [echo]               signed before it is published.
     [echo]               The 'nodeps' target can be used to only build the
     [echo]               current project and ignore the libraries using:
     [echo]               'ant nodeps release'
     [echo]    instrument:Builds an instrumented package and signs it with a
     [echo]               debug key.
     [echo]    test:      Runs the tests. Project must be a test project and
     [echo]               must have been built. Typical usage would be:
     [echo]                   ant [emma] debug install test
     [echo]    emma:      Transiently enables code coverage for subsequent
     [echo]               targets.
     [echo]    install:   Installs the newly build package. Must either be used
     [echo]               in conjunction with a build target (debug/release/
     [echo]               instrument) or with the proper suffix indicating
     [echo]               which package to install (see below).
     [echo]               If the application was previously installed, the
     [echo]               application is reinstalled if the signature matches.
     [echo]    installd:  Installs (only) the debug package.
     [echo]    installr:  Installs (only) the release package.
     [echo]    installi:  Installs (only) the instrumented package.
     [echo]    installt:  Installs (only) the test and tested packages (unless
     [echo]               nodeps is used as well.
     [echo]    uninstall: Uninstalls the application from a running emulator or
     [echo]               device. Also uninstall tested package if applicable
     [echo]               unless 'nodeps' is used as well.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Archiving artifacts
Finished: SUCCESS
```

In jenkins I dont check in my bin folders. Would that cause any issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Post-build action called Archive the artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to do with the build itself. For some reason it was coming up with success even tho nothing was building. I have to change a few more settings to get it to work. Also in the config page had to specify debug or release under Build - > Invoke Ant -> Targets

Also there were build.xml files missing from the library projects. So once I created all the build.xml files and added the targets it seems to be creating the apk file and can download it now.

Thanks for your help